# A growth rate query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query for a growth report by month. Let's say a company last month had a count of 4 products and this month 1 product; I want to show the 4 counts for the last month and then on current month show count as 5 basically adding last month's counts to this month and so forth. This will be for different companies and need to adding counts for all the years

I first built the below query that shows counts for each month and year by compan. When I tried using the lag function the numbers pretty much go off. Ideally for company1 the count for January must be added to February's count. The count for feb added to March's count and so forth

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT c.Name,YEAR(p.DateAdded) [Year], 
DATENAME(MONTH, p.DateAdded) [Month], 
COUNT(ProductID)
--+lag(COUNT(p.ProductID),1) OVER ( ORDER BY YEAR(p.DateAdded),DATENAME(MONTH, p.DateAdded)) 
ProductCount
FROM Product.Product p
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID,name from sourcing.Company WHERE CompanyTypeID=1 AND DateDeleted IS null) c ON p.ManufacturerID=c.id
WHERE p.DateArchived IS NULL AND p.ManufacturerID=571 AND YEAR(p.DateAdded) IN ('2015')
GROUP BY c.Name,YEAR(p.DateAdded), 
DATENAME(MONTH, p.DateAdded)) AS MontlySalesData ORDER BY MontlySalesData.Year,MontlySalesData.Month
```

Results:

| Companies | Year | Month | ProductCOunt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company1 | 2022 | February | 6 |
| Company2 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company2 | 2022 | February | 6 |
| Company3 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company3 | 2022 | February | 6 |

Expected results:

| Companies | Year | Month | ProductCOunt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Company1 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company1 | 2022 | February | 11 |
| Company2 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company2 | 2022 | February | 11 |
| Company3 | 2022 | January | 5 |
| Company3 | 2022 | February | 11 |
| Company3 | 2022 | March | 13 |
| Company3 | 2022 | April | 50 |

Answer (score 0):

You can start from the query that's gave you the result, Use it inside `WITH cte`
Then its will be easy to get your expected data if you use the cumulative `sum() over()` as follows :

```
WITH cte as (
  select *, row_number() over( order by (SELECT NULL)) as rn
  from mytable
)
select Companies, Year, Month, sum(ProductCOunt) over (partition by Companies ORDER BY rn ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as ProductCOunt
from cte;
```

Results :

```
Companies   Year    Month   ProductCOunt
Company1    2022    January     5
Company1    2022    February    11
Company2    2022    January     5
Company2    2022    February    11
Company3    2022    January     5
Company3    2022    February    11
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/9-A2GZP9)

Comment: thanks a lot man, this worked perfect, I now just need to PIVOT it and have the months as columns, Appreciated

Comment: Glad to hear :), If you see it useful can you accept my answer

Comment: Can't see where i can accept the answer but will do